# Cassandra: Set collection boolean, how to?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am making a columnfamily that will save values of different sensors.

**Sensor_04** will have boolean values of **4 different doors**. *door1, door2, door3,door4*.

The goal is to be able to query and ask for is door1,2,3 or 4 true or false?

How is the syntax done for this? Cause i know my example is **false:**

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY lockSystem (sID int, sNamn text, doors set<boolean>, PRIMARY KEY(sID));
```

**Wrong --->**

```
 INSERT INTO lockSystem (sID, sNamn, doors) VALUES (4,'Sensor_04' {'door1:True','door2:False','door3:False','door4:false'});
```

I hope my question makes sense, my goal is something like this:

Sensor_4: sID int, sName text, set: door1 bool, door2 bool, door3 bool, door4 bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assume that if a `door` is present in your set then its value is `true`, and then yuo can use the filtering capabilities of C* to query your data.

So I'd change the model to something like:

```
CREATE TABLE lockSystem (
    sID int, 
    sNamn text, 
    doors set<text>, 
    PRIMARY KEY(sID)
);
```

where the `doors` set has been changed to a set of text. You then add data into your set when one door alarm gets "high" with:

```
UPDATE lockSystem SET doors = doors + { '1' } WHERE sID = ?;
```

To filter you data you can then use:

```
SELECT * FROM lockSystem WHERE doors CONTAINS '1';
```

Have a look at the [using the set type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_set_t.html) documentation, and on how to [filter data in a collection](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_query_collection_c.html).